# Are computer-forensic questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I had a look into the first six [computer-forensics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-forensics) questions today and I think they are off-topic and hardly programming-related:

[File paths and carved files mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861036/file-paths-and-carved-files-mapping) might be better on SuperUser.

[Effectiveness of contrast enhancement detection techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272586/effectiveness-of-contrast-enhancement-detection-techniques) is probably too broad or opinion based.

[What should be included in a batch script to acquire IoC for a Windows PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961278/what-should-be-included-in-a-batch-script-to-acquire-ioc-for-a-windows-pc) is basically about programming a batch file, but asking for ideas on what to put inside, so that's opinion-based.

[Detecting carved-file type using ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786322/detecting-carved-file-type-using-ascii) has a highly upvoted duplicate on SuperUser.

[Where is MFT at NTFS filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398740/where-is-mft-at-ntfs-filesystem) is asking for NTFS internals, so potentially useful for programming but does not define the programming context, so this could also be an administrator looking at NTFS, which is SuperUser or ServerFault again.

[Theory, idea for finding copied shapes on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558256/theory-idea-for-finding-copied-shapes-on-an-image) is asking for a theory, so perhaps something for Programmers.

I flagged one of them but I didn't want to start a flagging spree before asking this question here on Meta.

Are above questions off-topic? Should we discourage [computer-forensics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-forensics) by making a statement in the tag wiki?

Comment: If it looks like slight polishing makes it fit better here, that would be a good edit.

Comment: @Deduplicator that's kind of a blanket statement. This is not about polishing poor questions, it's about off-topic questions. They have little to nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems like **computer forensics** could be a good [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I like this idea!

Comment: That sounds like it would be the 4th SE  I'd be happy to join. With the usual *caveat*: " Questions asking for help reverse-engineering a specific system are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem." (from [reverseengineering.se], so it needs some re-wording). IOW *not* "hi guys plz any1 help me rebuild my crashed hd!! omg im FREAKING,,,"

Comment: @Jongware so it would be for professionals or professionals-to-be instead of people wanting practical help (that are not in the field). That makes sense and would probably benefit from being explicitly so.

Comment: @slicedtoad: honestly that's not any different from Stack Overflow. At least what it hopes and aims to be, help vampires and rep whores and all. (Just the other day someone boasted having gained 100K in a year on answering easy GREP queries *only*. Sigh.)

Comment: @Jongware the lower traffic sites don't seem to have as much of a problem though. And ones like mathoverflow do quite well in this respect.

Comment: @Jongware 100k on **grep** questions... lol

Comment: So the answer is "yes", they are off-topic here?

Comment: Yes, and we recommend a new Stack Exchange site just for those topics.